# The minimal surfaces immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

Where can I find the result that states that the minimal surfaces immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are of revolution?

I was searching the internet but I do not think so.

Comment: this is false as stated. There are plenty of immersed, sometimes embedded, minimal surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: And what is the correct statement?

Comment: Where did you see this assertion? If you provide the reference it might be easier to see what are referring to.

Comment: It was in the abstract of this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.4211.pdf
I think I already found it, it looks like Schoen's Theorem

Comment: Surfaces of revolution are easier to calculate and visualize. Non  axisymmetric CMC surfaces can be physically realized by taking any closed loop and blowing air on one side to create constant pressure $p$ across a soap film of surface tension $T$ as it obeys the law for 2D surface with differential eqation $ \kappa_1+ \kappa_2 = p/T $ contained in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: The current form of the Question is both incorrect and overly terse.  You clearly did some research before coming here to ask for a proof (of something that isn't so), and in your Comment above you've shifted to "what is the correct statement?"  It would improve your Question considerably to edit it in such a way that your concern with the above linked article and desire to have a correct proposition are highlighted.